# ESLint wants setSate as a dependency for useEffect but this causes an infinite loop (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-hooks

I have the following situation:

```
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: ""
  });

  const [submitButton, setSubmitButton] = useState({
    disabled: true
  });

 useEffect(() => {
    const disabled = !(values.username.length && values.password.length);

    setSubmitButton({ ...submitButton, disabled });
  }, [values]);
```

This works perfectly fine and does exactly what I would like but ESLint complains with `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` warning.

When I do eslint autofix, it adds `setSubmitButton` as a dependency to useEffect, however that causes an infinite loop. This seems like such a simple situation but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've seen code of other people that use setState and the like within useEffect without declaring it as a dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [functional updater form](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) of `useState`, which will provide a snapshot of your state, thus eliminating the need for directly reference it.

```
setSubmitButton(previous => ({ ...previous, disabled }));
```

Since `React` already knows the current value of `submitButton` and will only run the callback when changing the state this will happen outside your component's scope and `eslint` won't be mad at you.
In [Dan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458193/dan-abramov) words

> I like to think of these cases as “false dependencies”. Yes, count was
>   a necessary dependency because we wrote setCount(count + 1) inside the
>   effect. However, we only truly needed count to transform it into count
>   + 1 and “send it back” to React. But React already knows the current count. All we needed to tell React is to increment the state —
>   whatever it is right now.

[Font](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: What if i need to directly reference that state? I have a use case where i have to update that state and also update another state based on that state.

Comment: this is too vague. Please consider post as a question with a more detailed description of your problem